# LinkedHashMap order

Tags: java, dictionary, linkedhashmap

Is order still guaranteed when the map objects are accessed as shown below at location 1 and 2?

```
    //.... 
    public void firstMethod(){
        Map<K,V> sortedMap=new LinkedHashMap<K,V>();
        sortedMap.put(h,g);
        //....

        Map<K,V> anotherMap=someOtherMethod(sortedMap);

        // order of anotherMap when read  ...2
    }

    public Map<K,V> someOtherMethod(Map<K,V> someMap){

         someMap.put(a,b);

         //order of someMap  when read ...1
         //.....

         return someMap;

    }
    //....
```

Comment: uh, what?  your question is a bit vague...

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?  `LinkedHashMap` isn't doing anything magical.

Comment: @LouisWasserman this maybe a silly question, I was not sure the effect of casting `sortedMap` to a 'Map' and the return from `someOtherMethod` being of type `Map`. @Zapl's answer below clears my doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the concrete instance of your `Map` object is a `LinkedHashMap` yes. It does not matter what you do with it. The object will keep it's data ordered and the implementation does not change if you cast to just `Map` or even `Object` or pass it to methods. It will stay internally a `LinkedHashMap`. You might no longer see that it is one if you cast it to `Object`.

Assuming that you don't know the source code, the only thing that is not guaranteed is that `someOtherMethod` returns your `LinkedHashMap`. It could also re-order it.

A method should not be trusted unless it specifies those things. But since you know the sourcecode here, you have the guarantee that it is your `LinkedHashMap` in perferct order.

Comment: Thank you. This clears the doubt I had. I was not sure what the effect would be when casting to `Map` even when the concrete type is `LinkedHashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order.

So even after things are inserted and removed, the order should persist through whatever you want to do to it.